# GNU/make and docker, terminate the running process

Tags: docker, signals, gnu-make

I'm using GNU/make (linux) to wrap some docker command, I don't use docker everyday so I'll forget the usage soon, one of those wrapper is `make serve`, it run `docker run` with `php -S` (built-in server) as command, it start and listen for connections.

To stop it I should use <kbd>^C</kbd> , I believe (but I'm not sure) the problem to be `make` intercepting the signal, the make's target fail but the php process (and the docker instance) remain running, I've to manually stop it.

I tried passing  `--sig-proxy=true` and `false` but with no effect, but I'm running the instance with a pseudo terminal (`-t`) so this was expected.

I wrote a bash wrapper to echo some message when some signal is trapped (`EXIT TERM SIGTERM SIGQUIT KILL SIGKILL`) and `exec php -S` , but I don't see any message.

I'm not sure what happen when <kbd>^C</kbd> is pressed on a running make, if the signal (and what) is propagated only to the forked `sh -c`, and why that wouldn't work with `docker run`.

I'd like to know if someone else had this problem and solved or if someone can think of some alternative solution.

**edit**

`Makefile`:

```
all:

.PHONY: docker-build serve

docker-build:
    docker build -f Dockerfile -t sigtest:v1 .

serve:
    docker run -t --rm sigtest:v1 gosu ubuntu:ubuntu php7.0 -S 0.0.0.0:8081 -t /home/ubuntu
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends php7.0-cli gosu 

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash ubuntu
```

test with `make docker-build` and then `make serve`

**2nd edit**

I managed to wrap `docker run` with a shell script <strike>(I'm not sure about trap syntax in posix shells, eventually I'll take a look)</strike>

`make` seems to be sending `INT` the first time and and then `EXIT`

```
#!/bin/sh
pid=$$
trap 'trap - INT EXIT; echo " signal received, wait..."; docker stop -t 0 sig${pid}; exit' INT EXIT
docker run --name=sig${pid} "$@"
```

and then in the `Makefile`

```
serve:
    -./docker-run.sh -t --rm sigtest:v1 gosu ubuntu:ubuntu php7.0 -S 0.0.0.0:8081 -t /home/ubuntu
```

I was hoping to not have to name the instances but that's the simplest way I can think of.

Comment: Could you post a simplified version of your `Makefile` which reproduces the issue?

Comment: Hello @DanilaKiver, see the edit, thanks

Comment: Had kind of similar issue before and switched to [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/). It has commands for managing the whole lifecycle including starting and stopping services.

Comment: Alex, sure, perhaps almost any solution removing make remove the issue, but that's the point, I been using make for years now, I'd like to continue. But you gave me an idea, maybe wrapping docker run with a script outside of the docker instead of wrapping php inside... I'll give a try, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in using `make` but in the Signal handling. Here is an [article](https://medium.com/@gchudnov/trapping-signals-in-docker-containers-7a57fdda7d86) describing it.

As I said before `docker-compose` manages the whole lifecycle of your services.

Here is a basic example of your app using `docker-compose`. By `make up` and `make down`(including `^C` ), so you can start and stop your service.
`Makefile`:

```
all:

.PHONY: docker-build serve

build:
    docker-compose build

up:
    docker-compose up

down:
    docker-compose down
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  my_service:
    build: .
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends php7.0-cli gosu

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash ubuntu

RUN mkdir -p /home/ubuntu
RUN php7.0 --version
ENTRYPOINT php7.0 -S 0.0.0.0:8080
```

Comment: That would be nice but I've some other target in the makefile, for instance to build from some source and exit (without listening), with different configurations (dev and prod at least), can docker-compose handle the scenario?

Comment: `docker-compose build` just builds service and `docker-compose up` will start `php` server by executing  `ENTRYPOINT php7.0 -S 0.0.0.0:8080` line from `Dockerfile`. There are more  complicated examples available https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted